# How do I restart my Unicorn server?

Tags: ruby, nginx, server, sinatra

I have a server which is running Unicorn and nginx. I've just done a `git pull` to get the most recent updates to my own code, and now I need to restart it.

In setting it up, I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-sinatra-based-ruby-web-applications-on-ubuntu-13), and did these steps:

> Start Unicorn

```
cd /var/www/my_server

unicorn -c unicorn.rb -D
```

> Restart nginx

```
service nginx restart
```

I now need to know how to restart it. Ideally, it should be a quick process, so that my server doesn't have any/much downtime when doing this in the future.

EDIT: I tried a few other things as suggested elsewhere, such as `killall ruby`, and rebooting my server. Now I'm at a point where I've done the above, it doesn't give me any errors, but when I try and load a page, it doesn't respond, and likely eventually times out (though I didn't leave it that long). If I stop nginx, it says "connection refused", so it's obvious that nginx is working, but for some reason it's not able to connect to Unicorn.

EDIT: On a whim, I typed in just `unicorn` and it seems to be having an issue with my project - missing gems. Makes sense. So that first edit is no longer an issue, I'm still interested in the most elegant way of restarting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the init script they provide

> One example init script is distributed with unicorn:
>   http://unicorn.bogomips.org/examples/init.sh

because there you have the `upgrade` method which takes care of your 
use case, restarting the app with zero downtime.

```
...
upgrade)
    if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
    then
        n=$TIMEOUT
        while test -s $old_pid && test $n -ge 0
        do
            printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
        done
        echo

        if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $old_pid
        then
            echo >&2 "$old_pid still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
            exit 1
        fi
        exit 0
    fi
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try send a HUP signal to the master process, doing

```
 kill -HUP <processID>
```

> HUP - reloads config file and gracefully restart all workers.
>     If the "preload_app" directive is false (the default), then workers
>     will also pick up any application code changes when restarted.  If
>     "preload_app" is true, then application code changes will have no
>     effect; USR2 + QUIT (see below) must be used to load newer code in
>     this case.  When reloading the application, +Gem.refresh+ will
>     be called so updated code for your application can pick up newly
>     installed RubyGems.  It is not recommended that you uninstall
>     libraries your application depends on while Unicorn is running,
>     as respawned workers may enter a spawn loop when they fail to
>     load an uninstalled dependency.

If you want to read more about unicorn's signals you can read more [here](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/SIGNALS)

Comment: I think OP wants to gracefully restart Unicorn, not RELOAD it

Comment: Right now, I've tried a few other things and my server is now down, so anything that restarts unicorn will be fine. How do I know what the process ID is?

Comment: I just did `pgrep unicorn` and I'm not getting any results.

Comment: try doing    pid "/tmp/unicorn.pid" on your unicorn's conf file, and then kill -HUP $(/tmp/unicorn.pid)

Comment: do not leave /tmp as your pid file on production

Comment: type "ps" and have a look for the Master Unicorn Process. then kill -9 <processID>

Comment: @TonyVincent I wouldn't do that

Comment: `kill -USR2 <processID>` worked for me. Where processID is the Unicorn's master process id.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04 try

```
sudo service unicorn restart
```

If you are using capistrano 
add this in deploy.rb

```
desc "Zero-downtime restart of Unicorn"
task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "kill -s USR2 unicorn_pid"
end
```

Comment: For that I just get `unicorn: unrecognized service`. I don't believe I'm using capistrano.